# Erro com fetchAll usando order by

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou fazendo um sistema de agendamento de tarefas.

Preciso mostrar essas tarefas pro usuário, criei um arquivo chamado `tarefas.php` para fazer a consulta no banco de dados MySQL:

```
<?php
    include_once 'conexao-calendario.php';
    include_once 'VerificarLogin.php';
    $usuario = $_SESSION['email'];

    $sql = "SELECT id, titulo, local, data, horario, status FROM eventos WHERE email = '$usuario' ORDER BY data, hora ";
    $select = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    $dados = $result->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    var_dump($dados);
?>
```

Sem o `order by` aparece o array correto, mas com ele dá o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\hope\tarefas.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\hope\tarefas.php on line 9

Comment: Você tem o campo `horario` mas faz ordenação pelo campo `hora`.  Provavelmente se olhasse o log de erros do PHP acharia o problema. Fora isso, tem `prepare` e tem `query` logo em seguida, seria bom rever qual vai usar. Tem outros problemas também, incluindo falta de sanitização de strings e mistura de maiúsculas e minúsculas nos includes.

Comment: Qual é a linha 9?

Comment: rodei seu script e não deu erro nenhum, o erro pode estar em outra parte do código (nos includes). Use o método prepare e evite sofrer sql injection

Comment: Pode mostrar a estrutura da tabela?